# MS Access Checkbox on report row

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, checkbox

I would like to add a checkbox to my report rows to be checked per row after i am done with my action for said row.

I have a list of items per report, i want to check the item once im done with it, and the check will remain even if i close the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a field to the report's source table called and then add a clickable bound checkbox control to the report.

[Here are steps for a textbox control](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-text-box-control-to-a-form-or-report-c51860c5-1091-4eef-a1a5-f207d9d46493#bm2).  Just choose a checkbox instead.  (found by scrolling the list of controls in the `Design` menu)

[image: checkbox]

Comment: @Gustav - it _is_ nifty isn't it? It's [Screen2Gif](http://www.screentogif.com/) I'm not gonna lie, answering this Q was partly just an excuse to try it out, after learning about it by asking someone else on a _different_ unrelated Q, just like you are! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly with the features I can use.

Comment: I was going to make an animated gif to show you how to make an animated gif, but I was worried it would cause a universal paradox

Comment: Or recursive. Interesting thought.